# how to convert a list to dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like this. containing question and its answer.

```
list=[['It has been noted that in __________________ urban cities quickly expanded rather than the slow evolution of urbanism in the northwest.',
      'Gujarat'],
     ['These traditions and cultures include Anarta Tradition c. 39501900 BC Padri Ware 36002000 BC PrePrabhas Assemblage 32002600 BC Pre Urban Harappan Sindh __________________ Pottery Burial Pottery 30002600 BC Black and Red Ware 3950900 BC Reserved Slip Ware 39501900 BC Micaceous Red Ware 26001600 BC.',
      'Type'],
     ['Later in the 18th century Gujarat came under control of the __________________ Empire who dominated the politics of India.',
      'Maratha']]
```

I want to convert in into given form.

```
output =[{'question': 'It has been noted that in __________________ urban cities quickly expanded rather than the slow evolution of urbanism in the northwest.','answer':'Gujarat'}, {'question': 'These traditions and cultures include Anarta Tradition c. 39501900 BC Padri Ware 36002000 BC PrePrabhas Assemblage 32002600 BC Pre Urban Harappan Sindh __________________ Pottery Burial Pottery 30002600 BC Black and Red Ware 3950900 BC Reserved Slip Ware 39501900 BC Micaceous Red Ware 26001600 BC.','answer':'Type'}, {'question': 'Later in the 18th century Gujarat came under control of the __________________ Empire who dominated the politics of India.','answer':'Maratha'}
```

Is it possible ? If yes , then how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) will suffice:

```
[{'question': q, 'answer': a} for q, a in list]
```

This outputs:

```
[{'question': 'It has been noted that in __________________ urban cities '
              'quickly expanded rather than the slow evolution of urbanism in '
              'the northwest.',
  'answer': 'Gujarat'},
 {'question': 'These traditions and cultures include Anarta Tradition c. '
              '39501900 BC Padri Ware 36002000 BC PrePrabhas Assemblage '
              '32002600 BC Pre Urban Harappan Sindh __________________ Pottery '
              'Burial Pottery 30002600 BC Black and Red Ware 3950900 BC '
              'Reserved Slip Ware 39501900 BC Micaceous Red Ware 26001600 BC.',
  'answer': 'Type'},
 {'question': 'Later in the 18th century Gujarat came under control of the '
              '__________________ Empire who dominated the politics of India.',
  'answer': 'Maratha'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: *(consider don't use [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) function as variable. list is a built-in function.)*

```
# >>> lst = list
>>> [{'question': l[0], 'answer': l[1]} for l in lst]

[{'question': 'It has been noted that in __________________ urban cities quickly expanded rather than the slow evolution of urbanism in the northwest.',
  'answer': 'Gujarat'},
 {'question': 'These traditions and cultures include Anarta Tradition c. 39501900 BC Padri Ware 36002000 BC PrePrabhas Assemblage 32002600 BC Pre Urban Harappan Sindh __________________ Pottery Burial Pottery 30002600 BC Black and Red Ware 3950900 BC Reserved Slip Ware 39501900 BC Micaceous Red Ware 26001600 BC.',
  'answer': 'Type'},
 {'question': 'Later in the 18th century Gujarat came under control of the __________________ Empire who dominated the politics of India.',
  'answer': 'Maratha'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following lines then you will get your desired output:

new_list = []

for data in list:

```
# data[0] contains first element and data[1] contains second element.

dict = {'question': data[0], 'answer': data[1]}  
new_list.append(dict)
```

Just create a new list and append data dictionary of question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this:

```
my_list = [['It has been noted that in __________________ urban cities quickly expanded rather than the slow evolution of urbanism in the northwest.',
  'Gujarat'],
 ['These traditions and cultures include Anarta Tradition c. 39501900 BC Padri Ware 36002000 BC PrePrabhas Assemblage 32002600 BC Pre Urban Harappan Sindh __________________ Pottery Burial Pottery 30002600 BC Black and Red Ware 3950900 BC Reserved Slip Ware 39501900 BC Micaceous Red Ware 26001600 BC.',
  'Type'],
 ['Later in the 18th century Gujarat came under control of the __________________ Empire who dominated the politics of India.',
  'Maratha']]
output = [{'question': item[0], 'answer': item[1]} for item in my_list]
```

TIP: DO NOT name your variables clashing with python built-in datatypes like list, set etc as it can have undesirable consequences